# Merging multiple animated armatures together?

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

I have multiple armatures and their own mesh here, and they all are animated with the same animation.

[image]

If I select all the armatures and press ctrl+J, then everything disappears except one armature and mesh, and they don't animate. How do I merge them together so that all the bones and meshes are still intact but it's all underneath one armature/model?

Comment: Joining the different armatures into one is essentially making a new one.  Your meshes and animations were made for the armatures you had before, not the new one. Blender tries to save things as much as it can, but it's no miracle. I bet the only one mesh that remains at the end is the active object before joining. Joining armatures together is not something expected to be done after animating. It's at best done while making rigs, and requires some cleaning afterwards. Why are you attempting to do that ?

Comment: This is for a game, and I'm trying to combine all of these individual models into one to save on performance in game. I guess I could do it manually, but I wondered if it's possible to quickly do it.

Comment: It can be done, with some adjusting, but the procedure depends on how did you build the scene. Please upload your file to get more help.